Filter Network requests by status code in Firefox browser console
How can I show only certain HTTP status codes in the Firefox browser console?
For example, I just want to see a list of all image requests that returned a 404 error. The console has a setting to show only Image requests (by hiding the others) but doesn't show a setting to filter the results by status code.

I found the way to filter by status code in the Network tab. Enter the parameter status-code into the open text filter field, followed by the status code you want to see.
Example:
status-code:404

Screenshot:

